# Understanding of Ravina's view on Churban timeline

Tags: talmud-gemara, arachin-tractate

I came across a Gemara in Arachin 12a

> מכל מקום תשסרי לרבינא קשיא
> The Gemara objects: In any case, the assertion of the baraita that the destruction of the Temple occurred in the nineteenth year is difficult for Ravina, because there are eleven years from the first exile until the year of the destruction, not counting the year of the exile or the year of the destruction, and then an additional fifteen years, including the year of the destruction, until the date mentioned in the verse in Ezekiel, which is a total of twenty-six years, not twenty-five. (Sefaria.org)

The Gemara is finding diffculty understanding a Pasuk which states the prophecy about the third Temple occured in the **25th** year from Ezekiel's exile. The Gemara asks on Ravina, surely there are *26* years not 25 years as the Churban took place in the second year of a 2 year exile. The calculation is: 11 years from Ezekiels's exile to the Churban (19th year of Nebuchadnezzar's reign) and another 15 years from the Churban until the prophecy (Yovel) = 26 years, not 25 as the pasuk stated.

I don't understand this calculation as surely if the Churban took place over two years, there were only 14 years from the Churban to the prophecy?

Please could you provide a clear explanation of the Gemara's difficulty at this stage as I don't see the difficulty.

Comment: Just for a fun fact- Today is Ravina's yahrtzeit!